# FileNotFoundException when uploading .mp3 file to server in android

Tags: android, filenotfoundexception

`FileNotFoundException` when uploading .mp3 file to server in android. Please help me.

```
 String sep = File.separator; // Use this instead of hardcoding the "/"
            String newFolder = "folderName";
            String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            File myNewFolder = new File(extStorageDirectory + sep + newFolder);
            myNewFolder.mkdir();
            outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() 
              + sep + newFolder + sep + Company_Name + "_"+dte+hh+"_"+mm+"_"+ss +".mp3";




HttpURLConnection conn = null;
                DataOutputStream dos = null;
                DataInputStream inStream = null;
                String existingFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + outputFile;
                String lineEnd = "\r\n";
                String twoHyphens = "--";
                String boundary = "*****";
                int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
                byte[] buffer;
                int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
                String responseFromServer = "";
                String urlString = "http://172.16.10.64:8080/plugleadservices/rest/feedbackmanagement/upload?company_id=1";

                try {

                    //------------------ CLIENT REQUEST
                    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(outputFile));
                    // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                    URL url = new URL(urlString);
                    // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
                    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    // Allow Inputs
                    conn.setDoInput(true);
                    // Allow Outputs
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);
                    // Don't use a cached copy.
                    conn.setUseCaches(false);
                    // Use a post method.
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                    dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + outputFile + "\"" + lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    // create a buffer of maximum size
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                    // read file and write it into form...
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                    while (bytesRead > 0) {

                        dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                    }

                    // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
                    // close streams
                    Log.e("Debug", "File is written");
                    fileInputStream.close();
                    dos.flush();
                    dos.close();

                } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                    Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
                }

                //------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
                try {

                    inStream = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                    String str;

                    while ((str = inStream.readLine()) != null) {

                        Log.e("Debug", "Server Response " + str);

                    }

                    inStream.close();

                } catch (IOException ioex) {
                    Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
                }
```

logcat:

```
06-06 13:11:46.389: I/System.out(25970): $$$$$$$ Output File : /storage/emulated/0/Plugleads/test6_06-06-201601_11_32.mp3
06-06 13:11:48.132: V/RenderScript(25970): Application requested CPU execution
06-06 13:11:48.145: V/RenderScript(25970): 0xb91082d0 Launching thread(s), CPUs 2
06-06 13:11:54.871: E/Debug(25970): File is written
06-06 13:11:58.529: E/Debug(25970): error: http://172.16.10.64:8080/plugleadservices/rest/feedbackmanagement/upload?company_id=1
06-06 13:11:58.529: E/Debug(25970): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://172.16.10.64:8080/plugleadservices/rest/feedbackmanagement/upload?company_id=1
06-06 13:11:58.529: E/Debug(25970):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:206)
06-06 13:11:58.529: E/Debug(25970):     at com.plugleads.feedback.record.Frag_Record.doFileUpload(Frag_Record.java:656)
06-06 13:11:58.529: E/Debug(25970):     at com.plugleads.feedback.record.Frag_Record.onClick(Frag_Record.java:524)
06-06 13:11:58.529: E/Debug(25970):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
06-06 13:11:58.529: E/Debug(25970):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19884)
06-06 13:11:58.529: E/Debug(25970):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
06-06 13:11:58.529: E/Debug(25970):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-06 13:11:58.529: E/Debug(25970):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
06-06 13:11:58.529: E/Debug(25970):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
06-06 13:11:58.529: E/Debug(25970):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-06 13:11:58.529: E/Debug(25970):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
06-06 13:11:58.529: E/Debug(25970):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
06-06 13:11:58.529: E/Debug(25970):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
06-06 13:11:58.530: I/Choreographer(25970): Skipped 228 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: File not found means file is not exists at your specific path!

Comment: It is there i am checking the filepath @Nirav

Comment: Perhaps log the value of `outputFile` just to be sure it points to the correct path. This might safe you time.

Comment: i am checking the oututfile @ishmaelMakitla, I have edited the logcat please check once

Comment: It has nothing to do with the MP3 file. Judging by the log the error occurs when you try to read the response from the server (HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream()). You can verifay this by checking the line numbers (656 in the Frag_Record class).

Answer (score 1):

A FileNotFoundException is thrown if your code can not find the file.

Since you have not added the location of your file to your question we can only guess where you put it.

**Make sure it is in the same path as your Javafile or change your code to the path where it is located.**

Answer (score 0):

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   http://172.16.10.64:8080/plugleadservices/rest/feedbackmanagement/upload?company_id=1

This error means, the URL doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes, because if the problem was your mp3 files, the logs would have showed that. Try hitting this URL through some client, like Postman.

Comment: Thanks @Eric, i will check with it.I will message you if I have any queries.